# How to use jwplayer with VAST

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I'm trying to use the jwplayer. I've successfully configured it for regular, non-VAST video ads. but it failed when I use vast like below:

```
<div id="thePlayer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("thePlayer").setup({
    flashplayer: "player.swf",
    height: "270",
    width: "380",
    autostart: true,
    advertising: {
        client: "vast",
        tag: "XMLFile1.xml"
    }
});
</script>
```

Error:

> No playable sources found.

I'd guessed that I should set the file option with a blank video and then it worked fine but it played the specified file in the file option not the vast:

```
file: 'Blank Video.mp4',
```

How can I make it works with VAST?

Comment: Is that your whole embed code? You also have to provide a link for a video that's why you are getting the 'No playable sources' message. It doesn't play only ads, but ads in relation to a video.

Comment: @Hyddan The link for the video is inside the VAST XML file. When I use vast I expect it plays the video inside the VAST file.

Comment: That is the idea, if it plays the main video but not the ad one then it is likely one of two things, either something wrong in your VAST XML (can you share the contents of XMLFile1.xml?) or perhaps wrong player edition. To play ads JW player requires you to have the 'ads' version of their player - do you have that one?

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the Players section in your Dashboard.
2. Click New Player or edit an existing Player.
3. Set your desired playback settings and other customizations.
4. Open the Advertising pane on the left-hand-side.
5. Turn Advertising on.
6. Choose the type of ad tag that you would like to associate with this player.

   a. VAST uses JW Player's own ad tag parser

   b. Google IMA uses Google's IMA SDK

   c. VMAP is an external ad schedule

   d. JW Player schedule is an advanced schedule that allows you to associate pre, mid, and post rolls with this player.
7. Enter the tag URL or URL to your VMAP file in the URL field.
8. Set the text for the user interface elements that you desire.

   a. Message for while the ad is playing.

   b. Cue text - the tooltip over the controlbar cuepoint.

VAST Example:
First, here is a basic advertising setup using a VAST/VPAID pre-roll:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer('myElement');
playerInstance.setup({
  file: 'assets/myVideo.mp4',
  primary: 'flash',
  advertising: {
    client: 'vast',
    tag: '//adserver.com/vastResponse.xml'
  }
});
```